# Fortran assignment overload with pointers

Tags: pointers, fortran, gfortran, assignment-operator

I want to overload the assignment for a type that I want to use for polymorphic pointers. I dont know the actual subtype the pointer is holding on runtime.
But the following example code reproduces the strange compiler error I get:

```
module example

type :: base_class
    real(4) :: some_garbage
contains

end type

type, extends(base_class) :: sub_class
    real(4) :: even_more_garbage
contains

end type

type :: main_operations_t
    class(base_class), pointer :: basic_pointer
    class(base_class), pointer :: pointer_array(:)
contains
    procedure :: main_operations
end type

interface assignment(=)
    module procedure assign_base_class
end interface

contains

subroutine assign_base_class(result_object, input_object)
implicit none
    class(base_class), pointer, intent(out) :: result_object
    class(base_class), pointer, intent(in) :: input_object
    result_object%some_garbage = input_object%some_garbage
end subroutine

subroutine main_operations(this)
implicit none
    class(main_operations_t) :: this
    class(base_class), pointer :: hack

    allocate(this%basic_pointer)
    allocate(this%pointer_array(2))

    this%basic_pointer%some_garbage = 0.0
    this%pointer_array(1)%some_garbage = 1.0
    this%pointer_array(2)%some_garbage = 2.0

    this%basic_pointer = this%pointer_array(1)
    this%pointer_array(1) = this%pointer_array(2)
    this%pointer_array(2) = this%basic_pointer

    this%basic_pointer = this%pointer_array(1)
    hack => this%pointer_array(1)
    hack = this%pointer_array(2)
    hack => this%pointer_array(2)
    hack = this%basic_pointer
end subroutine

end module
```

When I try to assign to the indexed pointer array i.e

```
this%pointer_array(1) = this%pointer_array(2)
this%pointer_array(2) = this%basic_pointer
```

I use gfortran 4.8.4 on Ubuntu.
I get a compiler error:

> Error: Variable must not be polymorphic in intrinsic assignment at (1) - check that there is a matching specific subroutine for '=' operator

The assignment to the 0d pointer however works without complaints.
The section with the "hack" pointer shows a possible workaround to get this to work in an ugly manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is complaining it needs a defined assignment. You do have one, but it requires pointers:

```
subroutine assign_base_class(result_object, input_object)
    class(base_class), pointer, intent(out) :: result_object
    class(base_class), pointer, intent(in) :: input_object
```

(It is not necessary to repeat `implicit none` in all module procedures. I'd argue it is a clutter which harms readability.)

And your variables are not pointers. `pointer_array(1)` is NOT a pointer even though `pointer_array` is a pointer.

A solution is to remove the unneeded pointer attribute:

```
subroutine assign_base_class(result_object, input_object)
    class(base_class), intent(out) :: result_object
    class(base_class), intent(in) :: input_object
    result_object%some_garbage = input_object%some_garbage
end subroutine
```

This compiles cleanly.

It would make sense to have the `pointer` attribute there if you were doing pointer assignment, but as it stands, there is no use of it in the defined assignment.